# Echo problems with execv() after fork()

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork

AFAICS, the child process inherits stdout/stdin from the parent process on fork(). This leaves me wondering why the following code does NOT work:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *earg[] = {"echo", "Hello", NULL};

    if(fork() == 0) {
        printf("running echo...\n");
        execv("echo", earg);
        printf("done!\n");
        exit(0);
    } else {
        sleep(2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When running this little program, the two printf() calls appear just fine on the console. But the call to echo somehow gets lost! The output on the console is just:

```
running echo...
done!
```

Can somebody explain to me why the echo output doesn't appear on the console? And how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`execv` will not search for `echo` command in the PATH, so it fails, and it prints out `"done"` (which should not happen if `execv` is successful). You must supply the full path for `execv` to work

You may want to use `execvp` instead. It will search for the `echo` command in the PATH variable.

Answer (score 4):

Since your `printf("done")` gets invoked your `execv()` clearly failed. All `exec()` functions do only return if an error occurred. Evaluating `errno` should help you to find out why it failed.

try using the whole path to `echo`:

```
 execv("/bin/echo", earg);
```

EDIT: if you want to print `done` as soon as the child exited you should add a `wait(NULL)` call to your parent. see the manpage of [`wait()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) for more information and an example how to use it.